# scapy.layers.inet couldnt be resolved

Tags: python, scapy

If i execute the code with Visual Studio Code on Windows, it works. But if I execute it in VSC on my Kali VM, i got the error "scapy.layers.inet couldnt be resolved"

. I cant figure out why. I installed scapy both times with the same version and Im using the same Python version.

```
import scapy.layers.inet


if __name__ == "__main__":
    src_ip = "1.1.1.1"

    dest_ip = "www.google.com"

    ip_layer = scapy.layers.inet.IP(src = src_ip, dst = dest_ip)
    print(ip_layer.show())
```

The only way to import scapy, which can be resolved is "import scapy". But then for examnple i get the error: "Module "scapy" has no attribute "layers""

Answer (score 0):

It might be a problem with the python path configuration, on windows it is possible that the path is added automaticaly but not on your Kali VM

begin by finding the path of your Scapy library on your Kali VM

```
pip show scapy
```

then add this path to the python library by adding the following line of code in the begining of your python script ( dont forget to replace the path in your code below) then this should work

```
import sys
sys.path.append("<path-to-scapy-library>")
```